# Getting account errors on remote server only - Antiforgery and AppData write permissions ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I guess I'm not understanding how the account (login/register) works in MVC.  On the dev server everything works fine.  When I deploy my application I get a couple errors:

> Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory

and

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I can fix the first error by enabling write permissions on the remote server, but everytime I publish it reverts permissions.  I didn't think I was using an sqlexpress anywhere in my app because my connection strings are for SQL server 2012 databases, but I'm not sure if MVC will create one just for the account controls, see connection strings below:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=MANDRAKE.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=DB1Name;Integrated Security=False;User Id=Username;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
<add name="BudgetingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BudgetModel.csdl|res://*/Models.BudgetModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.BudgetModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MANDRAKE.arvixe.com;initial catalog=DB2Name;user id=Username;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Another thing to note is I originally had this set up on my arvixe server as one website, and then I added a domain and published to that domain.  That is when the problems happened, but I don't see how that would be correlated.  I also added a captcha control to the user registration page, but when I remove that code, the errors persist.

Any ideas would be helpful, I don't know if I need to explicitly set the machinekey configuration (I didn't have to do that before, so I don't think I need to).

Comment: I tried adding a machine key to the web.config file and I got this error:  The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone's information it had to do with my user account on the arvixe server I have.  I don't know exactly what they did, but they told me that the permissions got messed up somehow.  I'm still unsure exactly what is going on.  I was trying to implement a captcha function but it seemed to mess everything up, possibly because the tutorials were outdated on how to add captcha to an ASP.NET MVC project.